# PHP MongoDB find() & cursor with nested Object

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following query syntax:

```
$collection = $client->golf->round;
        
$filter = ['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID( $roundId )];
$options = [
    'projection' => [
    'comp.id' => 1,
    'comp.courseId' => 1,
    'playerId' => 1
]
];

$cursor = $collection->find($filter, $options);
```

Normally I would simply use a `foreach ($cursor as $item) {}` to convert the retrieved data into PHP-native data types.

If I just `print_r($item)`, it outputs:

```
MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument Object ( 
   [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array ( 
     [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId Object ( 
       [oid] => 60cb076ab27d2d43235049c3 ) 
     [playerId] => 609d0993906429612483cfb1 
     [comp] => MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument Object ( 
       [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array ( 
         [id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId Object ( 
           [oid] => 607019361c071256e4f0d0d5 ) 
         [courseId] => 608473722f0d0d822c9394be 
       ) 
     ) 
   ) 
 )
```

I can get the `playerId` value with:

`$return['playerId'] = $item['playerId'];`

However, `comp` is a nested Object.

Whichever format I try to get to this data to convert into PHP data types fails.

Tried:

- Sub `foreach` loop on `$item['comp']`, but complains "Cannot use object of type MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId as array".
- Using array syntax, `$item['comp']['id']`

I would like to return the 3 projected values as a simple array of strings, for later use.

Comment: Have you tried accessing `comp` as object like this `print_r($item->comp);`?

Comment: Thanks @Haridarshan Knew it would be that simple. Just got stuck looking down the wrong path!